# Visual Composer shortcode for child theme dir

Tags: plugins, shortcode, visual-editor

I have a site using VC that is running on localhost and also on a staging environment.

I need to access the child theme directory to call images from within raw-html sections of visual composer elements.

I have created a shortcode plugin:

```
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Shortcodes plugin
 * Plugin URI: http://www.example.com
 * Description: This plugin allows access to theme urls in shortcodes
 * Version: 1.0.0
 * Author: Zach Keller
 * License: GPL2
 */

// Shortcodes plugin
add_filter('widget_text', 'do_shortcode');

function url_shortcode() {
    return get_bloginfo('url');
}
add_shortcode('url','url_shortcode');

function wpurl_shortcode() {
    return get_bloginfo('wpurl');
}
add_shortcode('wpurl', 'wpurl_shortcode');

function child_shortcode() {
    return get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory');
}
add_shortcode('child', 'child_shortcode');
?>
```

And I tried to map the shortcode in VC, but it wont render the images on the page. This plugin works with sidebar widgets by calling:

```
[child]
```

But when I use that in the VC elements, I get:

```
http://localhost:8888/seedbed/[child]/images/home/sb-icon.png
```

How can I use this child theme dir shortcode within VC elements?